# Local Plugin permission issue not apply on course manager specifically - Moodle

Tags: php, permissions, moodle, capability

I am new in Moodle and i have a task to create local plugin with course manager role. In my system i have bulk of users in specific course and they are categories in different roles. Some of are bind with students and rest of are Managers. For my case i have received request from the client to make a local plugin which generate multiple reports against student records. I have successfully made the plugin but the condition is this plugin only can access those one who has enrolled in course as a Manager. I m trying with following code which i share you in below but no success. right now only admin can access local plugin rest of are received error messages from the moodle state.

`["Sorry, but you do not currently have permissions to do that Project view "]`

No idea how it will be resolved.

Please advise.

local/project/db/access.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(

    'local/project:view' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_PERSONAL,
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
        ),
    'local/project:manage' => array(
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
        )
    )
    )
);
```

local/project/header.php

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config.php');
global $DB;
//Get the system context
$url = new moodle_url('/local/project/index.php');

require_login();
require_capability('local/project:view', context_system::instance());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully achieved the target against `moodle` permission. I have used `has_capability` method with course context and check authenticity with `require_capability`. Following procedure only work with `admin` and `manager` other would not access until when they get full rights from the site administration.

local/project/db/access.php

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(

    'local/project:view' => array(
        'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM,
        'captype' => 'write',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_COURSE,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW,
        ),
    )
);
```

local/project/header.php

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config.php');
require_login();

//Get the system context
$context = context_course::instance($course_id);

if (!has_capability('local/project:view', $context)) {
    require_capability('local/project:view', $context);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard Moodle role called 'Course manager'.

There is a role called 'Manager' ('manager') and another called 'Course creator' ('coursecreator').

If you have [debugging](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging) enabled you might get some extra warning messages if there is anything wrong with the code (e.g. if you have not run the install/upgrade process to create the capabilities or if you have not increased the plugin version number after creating the capabilities).

Comment: I have one more solution but its custom i checked user permission directly with the database its worked for me as i need but issue is this approach doesn't  provide me error function which display like moodle error messages. could you please advise how i can display same error messages which moodle use

`if(count($resposne) == 0){
 echo 'Sorry, but you do not currently have permissions to do that Project';
 exit();
}`

Comment: If you are having to manually check the permission in the database, then there is something wrong with your capability definition or your capability check. require_capability() and has_capability() have worked correctly for me thousands of times over the years I've been developing for Moodle.

Comment: for my case how could i use capability with require_capability() and has_capability()... there is no solution aspect moodle provided